# AttributeError: 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'get_transform' updating to Django 3.2.18

Tags: django

I'm trying to update to Django 3.2.18 but get this error.

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 608, in get_field
return self.fields_map[field_name]
KeyError: 'first'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1838, in _check_ordering
fld = _cls._meta.get_field(part)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 610, in get_field
raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: InteractiveSessionEvent has no field named 'first'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 917, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
all_issues = checks.run_checks(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 34, in check_all_models
errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1304, in check
*cls._check_ordering(),
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1845, in _check_ordering
fld.get_transform(part) is None and fld.get_lookup(part) is None
AttributeError: 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'get_transform'
```

I have upgraded all requirements to last version but the error still.

Any idea ? Somebody could help me ?